# Error while using two modals: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I really find it very hard to solve the above error.
I have two modals in my project. One of the modal is working fine and the other modal is not so. I have injected $modal as a dependency in the controller where I have created my first modal and I have injected $modalInstance as a dependency in the modalController and it works fine for me. I tried to create one more modal with the same steps and I have encountered unknown provider $modalInstance error.
Any answers will be appreciated.

Here is my code for first modal.

Controller:

```
angular.module('menu').controller('HeaderNavbarController', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 
function($scope, $modal, $log) {
 $scope.signin = function() {
        console.log('in signin');
        var modalnstance = $modal.open({

            templateUrl: '/modules/users/client/views/authentication/signin.client.view.html',
            controller: 'AuthenticationController',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                items: function() {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
        modalnstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            console.log('$scope.selected', $scope.selected);
        }, function() {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };}]);
```

View:

```
<div class="header-container top-header" ng-controller="HeaderNavbarController">
<li><a ng-click="signin()">SIGN IN</a></li>
</div>
```

ModalController: AuthenticationController

```
    angular.module('users').controller('AuthenticationController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
        function($scope, $modalInstance) { 
        $scope.cancel=function(){
            $modalInstance.close();
          }
}
]);
```

Template for Modal: signin.client.view

```
<div>
<button ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
</div>
```

Code for Second Modal

controller

```
angular.module('menu').controller('ScripsController', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 
    function($scope, $modal, $log) {
     $scope.focusInput = function() {
            console.log('in signin');
            var modalnstance = $modal.open({

                templateUrl: '/modules/menu/client/views/search.popup.html',
                controller: 'SearchController',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    items: function() {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalnstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
                console.log('$scope.selected', $scope.selected);
            }, function() {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };}]);
```

Modal view(HTML): search.popup.html

```
<div class="search-popup">
<button ng-click="closeSearch()">cancel</button>
</div>
```

ModalController: SearchController

```
angular.module('menu').controller('SearchController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance',
    function($scope, $modalInstance) {
      $scope.closeSearch=function(){
         $modalInstance.close();
}

}
}]);
```

I am getting unknown injector $modalInstance in the SearchController.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your module declaration

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this means you have recently upgraded ui-bootstrap from a version before 0.14 to one after 0.14.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes#modal

**Modal**

- Change: $modal for $uibModal.
- Change: $modalInstance for $uibModalInstance.
- Change: modal-transclude for uib-modal-transclude